How is my question opinion based? And what can I do to make it get answers?

I have a question about my Psychology & Neuroscience Stack Exchange post: Why is it that women's love for men's chest is not talked about and noticed a lot, comparatively?
I really don't understand how it is opinion based. In case of men, there's no doubt that most men find women's breasts sexually attractive. At the end of my question, I've give 4 possiblities, which I believe at least 1 of them is true. Either women's love for men's chest is more or it is less, as compared to men's love. So how it can be opinion based?
Please help me understand.

You have received a lot of feedback on a very similar question on Biology and received additional comments on Biology Meta - why start the same cycle on this site again? Bio and Neuro are similar sites, both are scientific stacks and the ample comments provided on Bio also apply here and vice versa. This kind of question fits better on Reddit or similar sites. There requirements are less stringent and opinion based questions lacking a firm scientific  framework are happily answered.

Do you mean if something is opinion based it's not a truth?

Nope, we attempt to confine the site to Q and A. This type of question undoubtedly will result in non-scientific discussions.

that's what I don't understand. How it is non-scientific discussion?
